# OCMock - how to mock accessibility in iOS

Tags: ios, testing, accessibility, ocmock

I am using xcode and my mocking frameworks is OCMock.  How can i use OCMock to mock that accessibility is turned on so i can run some simple accessibility UI tests ?

Should i mock `UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()`  if so how would i do that ?

i tried the following but it wont compile:

```
__block id mockClass = OCMClassMock (UIAccessibility.class);
```

it gives an error "use of undeclared identifer UIAccessibility". and that makes sense because its not a class. My end goal is to mock UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning() method , thats it. 
but it looks like its a C function and cant be mocked/overrided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned already, `UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()` is a function and not a method of a class. OCMock cannot mock functions.